# English Checkers game

Tags: python, python-2.x, checkers-draughts

I've written this English checkers game. Meanwhile, it's a human vs. human game, although it is easily extensible to a game between other players (such as a computer one).

```
"""Play English Checkers.
see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_draughts
"""

from collections import namedtuple
from itertools import cycle

# square - a number between 1 and 35, that isn't divisible by 9:
#    . 35  . 34  . 33  . 32
#   31  . 30  . 29  . 28  .
#    . 26  . 25  . 24  . 23
#   22  . 21  . 20  . 19  .
#    . 17  . 16  . 15  . 14
#   13  . 12  . 11  . 10  .
#    .  8  .  7  .  6  .  5
#    4  .  3  .  2  .  1  .
# Pay attention that in this representation, the numbers that are
# divisible by 9 are skipped - thus, two squares are adjacents if and
# only if their difference is 4 or 5. Also, this representation may
# be different from the representation that is used in the program's
# interface (for example, in `UserPlayer`).

# move - a tuple of squares - the first square is the piece we want to
#     move, and the others are the sequence of moves. Usually that tuple
#     is 2 squares long - it's only longer if the player made a multiple
#     jump.

# In some places of the program, the word "edges" will mean pairs of
# squares that have only one reachable square between them (in a
# diagonal line), so you can jump between them if they are both empty
# and there is an opponent's piece in the middle.
# The square in the middle of the two edges will just be called
# "the middle".
SQUARES = [s for s in xrange(1, 36) if s%9 != 0]

# a "jump" means both single and multiple jumps.

class MovingErrors:
    """A namespace for error constants for illegal moves."""
    NotASquare = "The move included a number that is not a square."
    TooShort = ("The move should start at one square and finish at "
                "another one.")
    NotYourPiece = "The player should move his own piece."
    MoveToPiece = "The player should move to an empty square."
    LongSimpleMove = "A simple move must include exactly 2 squares in it."
    NotKing = "Only a king can move backwards."
    JumpAvaliable = ("If a player can jump, he must do it; And if a player"
                     " can make multiple jumps, he must make all available"
                     " jumps in the sequence he chose.")
    JumpThroughKingRow = ("If a man jumps to the king's row, the move"
                          " terminates immediately.")
    SometimesJumps = ("If a move starts with a jump, ALL of it should be"
                      " composed of jumps.")
    WeirdCapturing = ("You have to capture your opponent's piece - not "
                      "empty pieces and not your own ones")
    JustInvalid = ("What. A simple move should move a piece to an adjacent"
                   " square, and a jump should jump above opponents. "
                   "Is that hard?")

### Checkers Stuff ###

class State(namedtuple('State', 'turn reds whites kings')):
    """A state in the English Checkers game.

    The board is always represented in the red's point of view, so the
    1-4 rank is the closest rank to the red's side, and the 32-35 rank
    is the closest rank to the white's side.

    Attributes:
        turn - the player that should play now - either State.RED or
            State.WHITE.
        reds, whites - frozensets of squares, where there are red and
            white pieces accordingly.
        kings - the squares where there are kings (red and white).
    These 4 attributes can also be like elements of a tuple - so you can
    unpack them:
        >>> turn, reds, whites, kings = state
    and you can access them also by doing state[n]. This is useful,
    because State.RED is 1 and State.WHITE is 2 - thus state[state.turn]
    will return all of the squares that belong to the current player.

    Other Attributes:
        opponent - the player that shouldn't play now, the opposite of
            self.turn.
        These attributes can't be accessed like in a tuple.

    Main Methods:
        state.move(move) - return a new state, that describes the game
            after the current player has made the given move.
        state.did_end() - True if the game ended, False otherwise.

    Other Methods:
        simple_move_avaliable(pieces) - return True if any of the given
            pieces can make a simple move. (The returned value may be
            incorrect if any piece can make a jump)
        jump_avaliable(pieces) - return True if any of the given
            pieces can make a jump.
        farther(s1, s2) - True if s1 is farther from the current player
            than the second square, False otherwise.
        pieces_after_simple_move(move) - Return a tuple of (red pieces,
            white pieces, kings), that describes the board's pieces after
            the given (not necessarily legal) simple move.
        pieces_after_jump(move) - Return a tuple of (red pieces,
            white pieces, kings), that describes the board's pieces
            after the given (not necessarily legal) jump.
    """

    RED, WHITE = 1, 2  # pay attention that state[RED] == state.reds and
                       # state[WHITE] == state.whites
    KINGS_ROW = {RED: frozenset(range(32, 36)), WHITE: frozenset(range(1, 5))}

    def __new__(cls, turn, reds, whites, kings):
        # now you can create a new state by passing any kind of iterable
        # as pieces
        pieces = [frozenset(filter(is_square, xs))
                  for xs in (reds, whites, kings)]
        self = super(State, cls).__new__(cls, turn, *pieces)
        self.opponent = cls.WHITE if turn == cls.RED else cls.RED
        return self

    def move(self, move):
        """If the given move is legal, make it and return the new state,
        after the move. If it is illegal, raise ValueError with an
        appropriate error message from MovingErrors."""
        self.stupid_errors(move)

        if are_adjacents(*move[0:2]):  # Simple move
            if len(move) > 2:
                raise ValueError(MovingErrors.LongSimpleMove)
            if self.jump_avaliable(self[self.turn]):
                raise ValueError(MovingErrors.JumpAvaliable)
            return State(self.opponent, *self.pieces_after_simple_move(move))

        elif are_edges(*move[0:2]):  # jump
            if not is_jump(move[2:]):
                raise ValueError(MovingErrors.SometimesJumps)
            if any(s in self.KINGS_ROW[self.turn] and s not in self.kings
                   for s in move[1:-1]):
                raise ValueError(MovingErrors.JumpThroughKingRow)
            if any(middle(*pair) not in self[self.opponent]
                   for pair in pairs(move)):
                raise ValueError(MovingErrors.WeirdCapturing)
            # If a man jumps to the king's row, he can't make more jumps.
            # Otherwise, if he can make more jumps the player must do them.
            new_board = self.pieces_after_jump(move)
            if (move[-1] in self.KINGS_ROW[self.turn] and
                    move[0] not in self.kings):
                return State(self.opponent, *new_board)
            temp_state = State(self.turn, *new_board)
            if temp_state.jump_avaliable([move[-1]]):
                raise ValueError(MovingErrors.JumpAvaliable)
            return State(self.opponent, *new_board)

        # Not a simple move, and not a jump
        raise ValueError(MovingErrors.JustInvalid)

        # Phew.

    def stupid_errors(self, move):
        """If the move has an "stupid error" (explained later), raise
        ValueError with that error from MovingErrors. Otherwise, do
        nothing.

        Stupid error - TooShort, NotASquare, NotYourPiece, MoveToPiece,
            NotKing.
        """
        if len(move) <= 1:
            raise ValueError(MovingErrors.TooShort)
        if not all(is_square(k) for k in move):
            raise ValueError(MovingErrors.NotASquare)
        if move[0] not in self[self.turn]:
            raise ValueError(MovingErrors.NotYourPiece)
        if any(s in self.reds|self.whites for s in move[1:]):
            raise ValueError(MovingErrors.MoveToPiece)
        if move[0] not in self.kings and not self.farther(move[1], move[0]):
            raise ValueError(MovingErrors.NotKing)

    def did_end(self):
        """Return True if the game has ended, and False if the player
        can do a move."""
        return (not self.simple_move_avaliable(self[self.turn]) and
                not self.jump_avaliable(self[self.turn]))

    def simple_move_avaliable(self, pieces):
        """Return True if any piece from the given iterable of pieces can
        make a simple move, False otherwise. It doesn't check if all of
        the given pieces exist. Also, if a jump is avaliable it won't
        return False because of that, so the returned value would be
        incorrect in that case."""
        assert all(piece in self[self.turn] for piece in pieces)
        for piece in pieces:
            for adj in adjacents(piece):
                if adj not in self.reds | self.whites:
                    return True
        return False

    def jump_avaliable(self, pieces):
        """Return True if any piece from the given iterable of pieces can
        do a jump, False otherwise. It doesn't check if all of the given
        pieces exist."""
        assert all(piece in self[self.turn] for piece in pieces)
        for piece in pieces:
            # Every jump starts with a single jump.
            for edge, mid in edges_middles(piece):
                if (edge not in self[self.turn] | self[self.opponent] and
                        mid in self[self.opponent] and
                        (piece in self.kings or self.farther(edge, piece))):
                    return True
        return False

    def farther(self, s1, s2):
        """Return True if the first square is farther than the second one
        (so the second square is closer to the current player's side),
        False otherwise."""
        return s1 > s2 if self.turn == self.RED else s1 < s2

    def pieces_after_simple_move(self, move):
        """Return a tuple of (red pieces, white pieces, kings),
        that describes the board's pieces after the given simple move.

        This method doesn't check that the given move is simple, or even
        legal, and won't necessarily raise an exception.
        """
        assert (move[0] in self[self.turn] and
                move[1] not in self.reds | self.whites and len(move) == 2)
        player = self[self.turn] - {move[0]} | {move[1]}
        if move[0] in self.kings:
            kings = self.kings - {move[0]} | {move[1]}
        else:
            kings = self.kings | ({move[1]} & self.KINGS_ROW[self.turn])
        return ((player, self[self.opponent], kings) if self.turn == self.RED
                else (self[self.opponent], player, kings))

    def pieces_after_jump(self, move):
        """Return a tuple of (red pieces, white pieces, kings),
        that describes the board's pieces after the given jump.

        This method doesn't check that the given move is a jump, or even
        legal, and won't necessarily raise an exception.
        """
        assert is_jump(move)
        single_jumps = pairs(move)
        captured = {middle(*p) for p in single_jumps}
        player = self[self.turn] - {move[0]} | {move[-1]}
        opponent = self[self.opponent] - captured
        if move[0] in self.kings:
            kings = self.kings - {move[0]} | {move[-1]}
        else:
            kings = self.kings | ({move[-1]} & self.KINGS_ROW[self.turn])
        kings = kings - captured
        return ((player, opponent, kings) if self.turn == self.RED
                else (opponent, player, kings))

### Square Stuff ###

def are_adjacents(s1, s2):
    """Return True if the two given squares are diagonally adjacent,
    False otherwise."""
    return abs(s1-s2) in (4, 5)

def are_edges(s1, s2):
    """Return True if two given squares are edges, False otherwise."""
    return abs(s1-s2) in (8, 10)

def middle(edge1, edge2):
    """Return the middle of the two given edges."""
    assert are_edges(edge1, edge2)
    return (edge1 + edge2) / 2

def edges_middles(s):
    """Return a list of all (edge, middle) tuples, where `edge` is
    another square that is an edge with the given square, and middle is
    the middle square of `s` and `edge`."""
    edges = [s + n for n in (8, 10, -8, -10)]
    middles = [middle(s, edge) for edge in edges]
    tuples = zip(edges, middles)
    return [t for t in tuples if is_square(t[0]) and is_square(t[1])]

def adjacents(s):
    """Return a list of all of the adjacent squares to the given square."""
    return [s+n for n in (4, 5, -4, -5) if is_square(s+n)]

def is_square(n):
    """Return True if the given number represents a square, False if it
    doesn't."""
    return 1 <= n <= 35 and n % 9 != 0

def is_jump(move):
    """Return True if each pair in the given sequence of squares is a
    pair of edges. False otherwise."""
    return all(are_edges(a, b) for a, b in pairs(move))

def rank(s):
    """Return the rank of the given squares. Counting starts from zero."""
    return ((s-s//9)-1) // 4

def human_square_to_normal(human_s):
    """Convert the given square from human representation (where squares
    are identified by numbers 1-32 and squares that are divisible by 9
    aren't skipped) to the normal program's representation.
    Raise KeyError if the square doesn't exist."""
    return SQUARES[human_s-1]


### Playing Stuff ###

# starting position of checkers
START = State(State.RED, xrange(1, 14), xrange(23, 36), [])

def checkers(red, white):
    """Play English Checkers between the two given players - red makes
    the first move. After each turn, yield the move.

    A player is a function that has two parameters - a state, and an
    optional parameter of an error. The state is an instance of the State
    class, that describes the current game, and the player should return
    its move, given that state. If the player gets the `error`
    parameter, it means that in the previous time it was called, it
    returned an illegal move - so it is called again, with the same state,
    and with an error from MovingErrors.
    """
    state = START
    yield None, state
    for player in cycle((red, white)):
        if state.did_end():
            return
        move = player(state)
        while True:
            try:
                state = state.move(move)
            except ValueError, err:
                move = player(state, str(err))
            else:
                break
        yield move, state

def display_checkers(game, upper_color=State.RED):
    """Display each state in the given game, from the first one to the
    last. The "game" is an iterable of (move, state) pairs (the state is
    the state of the game after the move), for example the one that is
    returned by the function `checkers`.

    `upper_color` is the color that its player's side appears at the
    top of the displayed boards. It can get one of two values:
    State.RED or State.WHITE.
    """
    for _, state in game:
        print_board(state, upper_color)

def play_display_checkers(red, white, upper_color=State.RED):
    """Play a game of checkers with the given players `red` and `white`,
    and display every new board.
    `upper_color` is the color that appears at the top of the displayed
    boards. (color = either State.RED or State.WHITE)
    See the docstring of `checkers` for more information about players.
    """
    display_checkers(checkers(red, white), upper_color)

def UserPlayer(dummy_state, error=None):
    """A player function that uses the protocol of the `checkers` function.
    It doesn't display the board to the user, but if there is an error, it
    will print it.
    It asks the user for a move in a human notation (where the squares are
    identified by numbers 1-32, instead of 1-35, and squares that are
    divisible by 9 aren't skipped). It returns the move in the program's
    notation.
    """
    if error is not None:
        print error
    inp = raw_input("What's your move? Seperate the squares by dashes (-). ")
    while True:
        try:
            human_squares = map(int, inp.split('-'))
            move = map(human_square_to_normal, human_squares)
        except ValueError:
            inp = raw_input('Invalid input. Try again: ')
        except KeyError:  # Because of human_square_to_normal
            print MovingErrors.NotASquare
            inp = raw_input('Try again: ')
        else:
            break
    return tuple(move)


### Utilities ###

def pairs(seq):
    """Return a list of all of the consecutive pairs in the sequence.
    Each element (except the first and the last ones) appears in exactly
    two pairs: one where it is the first element, and another one where
    it is the second one."""
    return [(seq[i], seq[i+1]) for i in xrange(len(seq)-1)]

def print_board(state, upper_color=State.RED):
    """Print the given state to the user as a board."""
    line = []
    # the first squares should be the upper ones.
    squares = SQUARES if upper_color == State.RED else SQUARES[::-1]
    # zip(*[iterator]*n) clusters the iterator elements into n-length groups.
    rows = zip(*[iter(squares)]*4)
    for row in rows:
        for square in row:
            player_ch = ('x' if square in state.reds
                         else 'y' if square in state.whites else '.')
            char = player_ch.upper() if square in state.kings else player_ch
            # == is used as an XNOR operator here
            if (rank(square) % 2 == 1) == (upper_color == State.WHITE):
                line.append('   {}'.format(char))
            else:
                line.append(' {}  '.format(char))
        print ''.join(line)
        line = []

###############

if __name__ == '__main__':
    play_display_checkers(UserPlayer, UserPlayer, upper_color=State.WHITE)
```

Comment: I welcome all feedback. If you want, you can choose only one aspect of the code to review (for example, the code in the "`### Checkers Stuff ###`" section, or the general structure of the whole code).

Answer (score 4):

I’m just going to dive in and run the script. Let’s see what happens!

- I get this instruction:

  ```
  What's your move? Seperate the squares by dashes (-).
  ```

  I’m nitpicking, but the correct spelling is “separate”.
- More concerningly, I’m not sure what I’m supposed to type here. How do I specify a square? Some sample input would have been useful, because I just typed the first thing that came to mind:

  ```
  What's your move? Seperate the squares by dashes (-). 23-45
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "checkers.py", line 417, in <module>
      play_display_checkers(UserPlayer, UserPlayer, upper_color=State.WHITE)
    File "checkers.py", line 357, in play_display_checkers
      display_checkers(checkers(red, white), upper_color)
    File "checkers.py", line 347, in display_checkers
      for _, state in game:
    File "checkers.py", line 332, in checkers
      move = player(state, str(err))
    File "checkers.py", line 374, in UserPlayer
      move = map(human_square_to_normal, human_squares)
    File "checkers.py", line 302, in human_square_to_normal
      return SQUARES[human_s-1]
  IndexError: list index out of range
  ```

  Looks like you’ve failed to range-check my input. Be careful – just because I give you something that looks like an integer doesn’t mean it’s correct.

  However, brownie points for not falling over when I try to type in non-numeric input.

  One case that could do with slight tidying: what if I specify multiple dashes?

  ```
  Invalid input. Try again: 1-3-5
  The player should move to an empty square.
  ```

  That should also count as invalid input.
- If I peek under the hood, I found a comment which seems to specify numbers that line up with cells. Okay, let me try that.

  ```
   . 35  . 34  . 33  . 32
  31  . 30  . 29  . 28  .
   . 26  . 25  . 24  . 23
  22  . 21  . 20  . 19  .
   . 17  . 16  . 15  . 14
  13  . 12  . 11  . 10  .
   .  8  .  7  .  6  .  5
   4  .  3  .  2  .  1  .
  ```

  Hmm, it didn’t behave quite as I expected (actual vs. expected on left/right):

  ```
  What's your move? Seperate the squares by dashes (-). 12-16
     y   y   y   y                        #    y   y   y   y 
   y   y   y   y                          #  y   y   y   y   
     y   y   y   y                        #    y   y   y   y 
   .   .   .   .                          #  .   .   .   .   
     x   .   .   .                        #    .   x   .   . 
   .   x   x   x                          #  x   .   x   x   
     x   x   x   x                        #    x   x   x   x 
   x   x   x   x                          #  x   x   x   x
  ```

  I’m not sure if that’s a bug or a misunderstanding on my part – but it is weird.

  I played a few more moves, and they didn’t quite line up with the grid in the comment at the top of the file.
- This is a rather unfriendly message:

  ```
  What's your move? Seperate the squares by dashes (-). 9-15
  What. A simple move should move a piece to an adjacent square, and a jump should jump above opponents. Is that hard?
  ```

  Don’t be condescending to your users, especially if you haven’t provided any good instructions for playing the game. It’s not my fault  if I don’t know what I should be doing.
- What’s going on with the number 9?

**The best thing you could do for this program is improve the introductory process.** It’s very difficult (perhaps impossible) to work out how to play the game from the instructions printed to stdout. The quality of your code is irrelevant if I can’t play the game.

---

I don’t have time to review the code properly, but here are a few things that jumped out at me:

- I was a bit confused by the name of the `is_square()` function, because it conflicts with my idea of a square number. Perhaps rename to `is_grid_square()`?
- There isn’t much wrong [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)-wise, except a bit of missing whitespace around operators and the fact that functions should be separated by two blank lines, not one.
- There’s a spelling error in a few method names: “avaliable” should be “available”.
- The docstring for `stupid_errors` reads:

  > If the move has an "stupid error" (explained later), raise
  >       ValueError with that error from MovingErrors. Otherwise, do
  >       nothing.
  >
  > Stupid error - TooShort, NotASquare, NotYourPiece, MoveToPiece,
  >           NotKing.

  I’m assuming the list of errors in the line below wasn’t what you meant by “explained later”, but I don’t find any other reference to stupid errors if I grep for “stupid”.

  I would also refrain from using derogatory terms like “stupid” to describe errors.
- I think this is just a bit bizarre:

  ```
  # == is used as an XNOR operator here
  if (rank(square) % 2 == 1) == (upper_color == State.WHITE):
  ```

  If you really want to do an XNOR operator, I think a more intuitive construction is

  ```
  if ~(condition1 ^ condition2)
  ```

  but the problem isn’t so much the way the condition is written, as the fact that I don’t know why the condition is significant. There isn’t a comment to explain why the code has been written this way.

  In general, there aren’t many comments in this file, which make it hard to read, review and maintain.

Comment: OK, thanks. The interface doesn't use the internal representation of squares, but rather the more common one, where squares that are divisible by 9 do exist - I will add instructions for that.

Answer (score 2):

I have some notes on comments, naming and other ways that you communicate your code's intent. You have a lot of comments and try to give information, but there's room to improve it.

---

Reading through and this sentence sets off an alarm:

```
# In some places of the program, the word "edges" will mean
```

"edges" only means the edge of a square in some places? Why is the meaning of this contextually based? From checking the usage, I see that you're consistently using "edges" to actually mean just one thing. Be careful of opening your documentation with unclear language like this, it makes a user go down entirely the wrong path. It'd be better to say

```
# In this program, the word "edges" means
```

So it's more clear and definite, not changeable. It also is odd how much you danced around the definition of edges. I thought at first you meant the corner squares from which there's only one square to move to (unless you can jump over the opponent's piece/s). Why not just say they mean the edges of the board? Unless there's semantics I'm missing, that would mean the same and be clearer to a user reading your script. After all, they haven't gotten to any of the logic used to calculate the edges yet, and that seems to be what your definition is concerned with.

Now you start talking about move in this long comment too, why not just in the `move` function? Oh, because *move* is used in two entirely different contexts. Even worse you're passing `move` tuples to the `move` method. This is circular sounding and confusing. Much better would be something like maybe passing a tuple named `positions`. Just think about how readable `piece.move(positions)` is, and you wont confuse the user about which is which.

Your errors being collected together and all named is a good idea, but they don't need to be a class. A dictionary works fine. And since they're constants, they should be named in UPPER_SNAKE_CASE. It's the convention for Python constants, and makes it clear that you haven't created `Exception` objects, they're just string constants.

MOVING_ERRORS = {
    # A namespace for error constants for illegal moves.
    "NOT_A_SQUARE": "The move included a number that is not a square.",
    "TOO_SHORT": ("The move should start at one square and finish at "
                  "another one."),

You misspelled available in `simple_move_avaliable` every time it came up. If that was a copy pasted typo, be careful of them as you can entirely miss an error that way that only gets found when a user tries to play with your code.

You should use inline comments sparingly, a sign not to use them is when they're too long to fit on one line and the formatting is ruined a bit by having it inline.

```
RED, WHITE = 1, 2  # pay attention that state[RED] == state.reds and
                   # state[WHITE] == state.whites
```

I think this is better:

```
RED, WHITE = 1, 2  
# Note state[RED] == state.reds and state[WHITE] == state.whites
```

Aside from `stupid_errors` being a bit insulting, it's not a good name because it doesn't indicate to me what trait these errors share. In addition to that, it implies that there is an error that needs to be dealt with but it's actually checking if there are errors. You should instead call it `validate_input` or `is_valid_input`.

One last note, having a lot of docstrings is great, you're trying to inform the user of what each does. But the format could be better. They should have one single line summary, then an empty line and then extra details.

```
def jump_avaliable(self, pieces):
    """Returns whether or not any piece given can do a jump

    Takes a list 'pieces' and returns a boolean.
    It doesn't check if all of the given pieces exist."""
```

Read the [PEP specifically about docstrings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) to learn more.

Comment: I'm now thinking about it, and I'm not really sure that making MOVING_ERRORS a dictionary is a good idea. If a typo is made (for example `MOVING_ERRORS['TWO_SHORT']`), `KeyError` - "could not be found" - will be raised, instead of `AttributeError`- "does not exist". (the latter is better - the dictionary will never be changed). I also find that the occasion of using dictionaries of constants is quite rare. Are you sure about that?

Comment: @MrHezi It's mostly personal preference really. A dictionary is designed to hold a collection of related values while a class isn't really *designed* for this even if it can do the same job. There's no particular downside to your approach that I'm aware of, except that initially I thought you were creating actual Exceptions and not just string messages. If you used UPPER_SNAKE_CASE the usage would probably be clear enough for people to understand that it was just a string.